# How do I switch to the cmd in windows without an installation media?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd.exe, console

I want to go to the Windows command prompt on Windows. I'm aware that you can open the console as a regular win32 application, but I want to use the console without the gui or anything, like what you see on FreeBSD or Arch Linux.

I'm aware that this can be done using a windows recovery media, but I want to do this without rebooting.

Comment: The last windows operating system I saw that could do this was Windows 98.  I have not seen this capability in any modern Windows operating system.

Comment: Windows recovery media...I believe that environment is called WinPE, but thats more than cmd, but like a minimal Windows with limitations. Another variation is called windows 'server core', this canot be done with regular windows client

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core

Comment: Windows is not Linux.  Even if you could pull of replacing the GUI shell (explorer) it is going to be a royal PITA to manage everything from the command line.  There are server windows versions that are headless (the name for what you want) but the only way to do it for non-server version of windows is to run the PE environment.  If you want it that bad, you are probably running the wrong OS.

Comment: Can you further explain how you DO want to get into command? Are you trying to make the system boot directly to a command line? If so, please say that.

Comment: @music2myear no, I want to switch to it, like what happens when you select log out on kde5

Answer (score 1):

You can "switch" to a CLI in Windows: just open your preferred CLI utility or program and open it.

As you don't want that, the other answer is that what you want is not possible and hasn't been possible in Windows consumer versions released in the past 20 years.

You get that "ability" in Linux and other Unix variants because they were and remain CLI OSes with GUIs running on top of the CLI, like Windows did back in the 80s and 90s. Beginning with Windows XP (I believe) Windows has not been a CLI OS with a GUI tacked on, and the CLI included in Windows is for some advanced functions, not for general use.

Because this is baked in to how Windows is coded from the ground up, what you want is not possible.